# How I can access the remote Desktop jenkins on another systems?

Tags: jenkins, remote-desktop, jenkins-agent

I had configure the URl on remote Desktop jenkins but unable to access that jenkins on Local system as I hit that jenkins URl on my local system.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to access Jenkins running on a different machine from your machine?

Comment: Trying to access jenkins from remote desktop to any local system.For that aws ec2 instances I have created.

Answer (score 1):

This is a networking/DNS concern.

`localjenkins` doesn't resolve - you'll have to use the FQDN or IP address, assuming you can route traffic between the two machines.